# Old category link redirection

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I was trying to solve broken links problem with URL rewrite for category, but I've noticed, that it's not working well.

I've changed category link from `category.html` to `proper-link-to-category.html`

After that, I've added URL rewrite, so old link won't display 404 page. So far, so good.

Lately I got a lot of errors in Google Webmaster Tools, there's a lot of 404 links like:

`category.html?___store=default&limit=30`

Is there a way to add wildcard to URL rewrite, or the only solution is to add own rules into `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2):

adding the rewrite rules via .htaccess would be the more stable solution.

The url rewrite in magento works in general, but problems/conflicts are not so easy to solve if they occure.
For example your example should work without a problem, it should have added a proper redirect on change of url-key anyway. Even Get parameter should not be a problem here, even if they get lost on a redirect.

So the simple answer is: yes, its not possible to do this via magento :/ you should prefer a solution via .htaccess